# Add Code Style for gsp in Intellij 2018.1.4

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gsp

I am writing .gsp code using Intellij 2018.1.4 and nothing is highlighted or indented. It just seems like plain text. When i create a html file, all the code style is added, but for gsp nothing is done.

i've tried searching for some plugin that is needed, but cannot find that either. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Check your [file types](https://i.imgur.com/9lqZl68.png). You may need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for some features, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, that worked, in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @CrazyCoder for that suggestion. I checked the [file types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8pRW.png) setting that you mentioned, and gsp was not available there. I am using the community edition and can't get the ultimate one. But, the work around is that I added *.gsp as registered pattern for HTML recognized file type, and this does solve most of the problem, if not completely